# Autenticação Memcached + Tomcat

Tags: segurança, tomcat, autenticação, memcached

Estou testando o [Memcached](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/) para implementar failover em meus servidores Tomcat.

Há alguma forma de implementar segurança via usuário/senha?

O Memcached vai ficar em um IP público e, por isso, acho inseguro que ele fique exposto sem algum tipo de autenticação.

Answer (score 2):

A documentação do Memcached possui [uma página sobre autenticação SASL](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLAuthProtocol), sendo esta a solução recomendada para o cenário exposto.

A configuração parece ser simples. Basta olhar o [*How-To* disponibilizado](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/SASLHowto).

Não sei exatamente qual a necessidade em ter um cache disponível na web, já que o acesso à "distância" pode tanto gerar instabilidades de conexão quanto eliminar o ganho de desempenho devido aos atrasos da rede. Dependendo do que você quer, considere usar um Web Service RESTful para abstrair o seu cache.

Comment: É que vou ter um balanceamento entre 2 servidores (sticky session), mas quero que um servidor assuma a sessão em caso de falha do outro (failover). O problema é que meus servidores ainda não estão na mesma subnet, por isso preciso trafegar pela rede pública.

Comment: Eu até vi esse how-to, mas não consegui implementar. Não consegui fazer o Tomcat se conectar (usei parametros usename e password no context.xml)

Comment: @NilsonUehara Aquela configuração seria do Server. Na parte do client, vai depender da biblioteca que você está usando suportar o SASL. Veja o [spymemcached](https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/wiki/Examples#Establishing_a_Binary_Protocol_SASL_Connection), por exemplo.

Comment: Achei o problema! Faltava inserir o parâmetro memcachedProtocol="binary" no context.xml